# Why bindAttr is not working with arrays

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am just curious why in my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sauliuslx/QGUbE/6/) `bindAttr` is not working with arrays. Is it going to be implemented in future or made on purpose or I am missing something?

**Handlebars**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>Using bindAttr with objects</h1>
  {{#each App.residents}}
  <div {{bindAttr class="isIrish:irish"}}>{{name}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>Using bindAttr with arrays</h1>
  {{#each App.residents2}}
  <div {{bindAttr class="[1]:irish"}}>{{[0]}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

​**javascript**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    residents: [
        {name: "St. Patrick", isIrish: true},             
        {name: "Leprechaun", isIrish: true},        
        {name: "Saulius", isIrish: false},                
    ],
    residents2: [
        ["St. Patrick",true],
        ["Leprechaun",true],
        ["Saulius",false],        
    ]
});
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to make this work:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>Using bindAttr with arrays</h1>
  {{#each resident in App.residents2}}
    <div {{bindAttr class="resident.lastObject:irish"}}>{{resident.firstObject}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

​

Comment: Aha. Yes indeed. Very well. Other way is to use `class="this.lastObject:irish"` probably. But it's a matter of taste. Thanks.

Comment: Have to wait a minute to go.. :-)

Comment: I wanted to take more time around your question. My solution works only for arrays with two elements. I don't find a way to resolve this in an general case. On the other hand, I wonder why you need this feature. If this is a real need, you could push an issue in the ember repo, linking this question, and see what happen ^^

Comment: That's right. I also did not find any generic solution. So I'd better go with objects. It's just because I am rewriting some solution where data comes in array form which saves bytes. Thanks anyway.